# CMB2 Encrypt field data

Tags: wordpress, encryption, cmb2

I'm using the CMB2 library for my wordpress system and we will be requesting users to input some personal data.

Is it possible to somehow encrypt the data posted into certain custom-fields?
Thanks in advance!